# Is this picture showing the relative sizes of atomic orbitals correctly?

Tags: atomic-physics, orbitals

I want to visualise how various orbitals are arranged in a multi electron atom. And main confusion Im having is how large or small are certain Orbitals.

So is the picture attached giving a good estimate of relative sizes?

(I got this form [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital).)

[image]

Comment: The first problem with your question is that these are single electron orbitals. Multi-electron wave functions can not be visualized this way because they don't "live" in 3d space. A two-electron wave function lives in six dimensions and n-electron wave functions depend on 3n coordinates. What you have seen in chemistry books are NOT the physically correct quantum mechanical solutions but merely (ad-hoc) approximations that are "good enough" for many chemical purposes, but they don't represent the actual physics of the problem.

Comment: @FlatterMann The question is speaking about atomic orbitals, not the exact many-body wavefunctions. By definition, the orbitals are one-electron states.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 The first sentence in the OP's question is indicating that he may not be aware of the problem.

Comment: Colour scaling is not the same for different orbitals. They are not normalised in the way they are displayed.

Comment: @yarchik what do you mean by color scalling?

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Imagine you convert the colour at each point to wave-function values. Then you properly integrate this data. The wave-function should be normalised. This seems not to be the case. Compare 1s and 3s. They have the same range of colours, but 3s is much more extended.

Comment: @yarchik, in this kind of plot, the extension is easily appreciated. The values aren't, otherwise, the shape of the wavefunctions would not be clearly defined.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Thanks for repeating what I have said. What's more, the size too would not be clearly defined. As the matter of fact, all orbitals stretch to infinity. With growing n their mean radius grows, their deviation from the mean grows too.

Answer (score 4):

You can work out the mean radius from the hydrogen wave functions:

$$ \langle r \rangle = \frac{n^2 a_0} Z
\Big(1+\frac 1 2\big( 1 - \frac{l(l+1)}{n^2}\big)\Big)
$$

so they look about right. As far as the electron's position, the images shown need to be squared to get a probability density, which will change the distribution a bit.

When visualizing a real atom, to the extent that that is possible, remember: they eigenstates are approximate; the atom has no idea what your $z$-axis, so there is no inherent direction to orient the states, and the sum of probabilities over all $m$ at fixed $n, l$ is spherically symmetric.

Comment: Notice that the figure caption in the wilipedia page says "3D views of some hydrogen-like atomic orbitals showing probability density and phase". Therefore what is plotted is already $|\psi|^2$.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I disagree. The page claims it's $|\psi|^2$, colored by $sgn(arg(\psi))$, but the figure for 2P disagrees. On the unit sphere (normalized to 1), it's just $Y_1^0\rightarrow \cos\theta = z$...ofc the sign agrees, but if you plot $|z|$ vs angles, you get two $r=\frac 1 4$ spheres tangent to the each other and the $xy$ plane, at the origin. $z^2$ is two prolate objects (maybe ellipsoids), and that figure looks like the former, not the latter.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the plots on the Wikipedia page, and they correspond to what is described in the caption. The reason for the non-evidence of the prolated objects is just the perspective (the orbitals are not viewed in a direction parallel to the xy plane.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 yes, tilted ellipsoids are spheres.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the problem is that it cannot be plotted so simply. Just looking at the spherically symmetric $s$ orbitals, it is clear that the different energies would affect each other. They will also change per type of atom. Why are you looking for scale accurate versions of these pictures?

Comment: 1. When we say electrons go in 3d Orbital after 4s, are these 3d electrons "deeper/beneath" 4s?

Comment: Actually, no. It is often that 4s is filled first, then 3d, meaning that 4s is deeper. Things are complicated.

Comment: Overlapping is necessary.

Comment: Ask your questions in full in the main thing. Don't clutter the comments like this.

Comment: Part of your answer should be a comment. The remaining part is not clear at all (what does "different energies would affect each other" mean?)

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 The wavefunctions need to keep the orthogonality, but each inner core electron sees an effective charge that is larger than the effective charge seen by the outer electrons. The sizes must thus be interacting in a very complicated way.